# Signal and slot Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I’m trying to write a very simple calendar program (I’m trying to learn Qt). The program itself is very basic, all it does is open a dialog box which displays today’s date with a button next to it. When the button is pressed another dialog opens, which I’ll call the calendar picker.

Here is the gist of the program: First, the main dialog opens with the current date. Then when the button shown in the picture is pushed, a signal is sent to a function which opens the picker and sets up a connection between the two classes which I'll describe below! The picker opens in which you can choose a date if you want. Let's say you choose a date by double clicking it. A signal is then sent to a function which closes the picker and the function then emits a signal to the main dialog to update the date to the new date. Now here's the problem:

Both the main dialog and the picker are in separate classes and I'm trying to set up a connection between the two classes when an item is double clicked.

***EDIT: Ok, now my problem is that I have Picker *mypicker declared in my header file and when I try using it in the .cpp file for example mypicker->show(); it causes the program to crash. Anyone know why?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

`undefined reference to MainDialog::updateDate(QDate)`

Usually means that the compiler or the linker can't find the reference to it.  So in your header, you make a promise that it will exist.

Then if when matching things up later the reference was never found... you get an error.

So what probably happened is one of a few things:

In your maindialog.cpp file you have:

```
// Either no definition of updateDate at all,  Wrong because you put in your header a declaration for one.

void updateDate(QDate date) // Wrong because it doesn't specify MainDialog
{

}


void MainDialog::updateDate() // Wrong because it doesn't match the parameter list
{

}

void MainDialog::updatedate(QDate date) // Wrong because the function name is off
{

}

QDate MainDialog::updateDate(QDate date) // Wrong because return type is off
{

}

void MainDialog::updateDate(QDate date) // Correct!  Matches the header file perfectly!
{

}
```

Then after you get past that, and other compile errors, keep an eye on the Application Output, because the connect call is a runtime connection, so it won't report a syntax mis-alignment until at the moment a connection is attempted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much for all the cases. It helped me figured out my problem. Also do you think you could help me with one other little thing. I have a pointer declared in my header file. Nothing special just declared as Picker *picker. However, when I try to do something like picker->show(); or try to connect in the .cpp file as I did above the program crashes. Do you think you would know why that happens?

Comment: A pointer is just a memory address.  Memory addresses on the heap that don't have an object allocated on them are worthless.  They are null, and accessing them causes errors.  You need to call `picker = new Picker;` before any line of code accesses it.

Comment: Also it is good practice to set all pointers like that to zero at the top of your constructor, and then before accessing them you can check to see if they are non-zero with `if(picker)`.  After you call `new` and allocate memory to the location, it is no longer zero and `if(picker)` will return `true`.